# Add a Countdown Timer that increments in JavaScript and resets per level(Resovled)

Tags: javascript, game-mechanics, html5, timer, jquery

I am currently developing a Simon says type game using jquery and javascript.

I have linked a fully copy of the game on github

Github download and unzip to see the game fully https://github.com/Jamiex304/Simon_Says_Game_Demo(Disabled because resolved)

And I have reached a problem I want to add a timer that the player can see ?

currently the level will just go on til the user clicks the wrong button in the sequence.

Some Basic info on the game the user will see a random sequence each level a new sequence is added with one more extra move Each time the user enters the right sequence they go to the next level all info can be found in the attached JavaScript with comments

WHAT I WANT HELP ADDING

I just want to add a timer that starts at 10 seconds when the user clicks the start button Each time the enter the right sequence the timer starts again when they reach 5 right sequences the timer adds 5 extra seconds and so

I already have a div made for it called Timer so the user can see it in the middle of the screen

I have attached the html code and the JavaScript that the game events and the github link offers the full game

Javascript

```
var game={ //game object
    level: 1, //current level
    turn: 0, //current turn
    difficulty: 1, // user difficulty
    score: 0, //current score
    active: false, //whether a turn is active or not
    handler: false, // whether the click and sound handlers are active
    shape: '.shape', // cached string for the pad class
    genSequence: [], //array containing the generated/randomized pads
    plaSequence: [], //array containing the users pad selections

    init: function(){                   //initialises the game
        if(this.handler === false){     //checks to see if handlers are already active
            this.initPadHandler();      //if not activate them
        }
        this.newGame();             //reset the game defaults

    },

    initPadHandler: function(){

        that=this;

        $('.pad').on('mouseup',function(){

            if(that.active===true){

                var pad=parseInt($(this).data('pad'),10);

                that.flash($(this),1,300, pad);

                that.logPlayerSequence(pad);

            }
        });

        this.handler=true;

    },

    newGame: function(){            //resets the game and generates a starts a new level

        this.level=1;
        this.score=0;
        this.newLevel();
        this.displayLevel();
        this.displayScore();

    },

    newLevel: function(){

        this.genSequence.length=0;
        this.plaSequence.length=0;
        this.pos=0;
        this.turn=0;
        this.active=true;

        this.randomizePad(this.level); //randomize pad with the correct amount of numbers for this level
        this.displaySequence(); //show the user the sequence

    },

    flash: function(element, times, speed, pad){ //function to make the pads appear to flash

        var that = this;                        //cache this

        if(times > 0){                          //make sure we are supposed to flash
            that.playSound(pad);                //play the corresponding pad sound
            element.stop().animate({opacity: '1'}, {        //animate the element to appear to flash
                duration: 50,
                complete: function(){
                element.stop().animate({opacity: '0.6'}, 200);
                }
            });                                             //end animation

        }

        if (times > 0) {                                    //call the flash function again until done the correct amount of times 
            setTimeout(function () {
                that.flash(element, times, speed, pad);
            }, speed);
            times -= 1;                     //times - 1 for each time it's called
        }
    },

    playSound: function(clip){              //plays the sound that corresponds to the pad chosen


        var sound= $('.sound'+clip)[0];
        console.log(sound);
        console.log($('.sound'+clip));
        sound.currentTime=0;                //resets audio position to the start of the clip
        sound.play();                       //play the sound


    },

    randomizePad: function(passes){         //generate random numbers and push them to the generated number array iterations determined by current level

        for(i=0;i<passes;i++){

            this.genSequence.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        }
    },

    logPlayerSequence: function(pad){       //log the player selected pad to user array and call the checker function

        this.plaSequence.push(pad);
        this.checkSequence(pad);


    },

    checkSequence: function(pad){           //checker function to test if the pad the user pressed was next in the sequence

        that=this;

        if(pad !== this.genSequence[this.turn]){    //if not correct 

                this.incorrectSequence();

            }else{                                  //if correct
                this.keepScore();                   //update the score
                this.turn++;                        //incrememnt the turn

            }

        if(this.turn === this.genSequence.length){  //if completed the whole sequence

            this.level++;                           //increment level, display it, disable the pads wait 1 second and then reset the game
            this.displayLevel();
            this.active=false;
            setTimeout(function(){
                that.newLevel();
            },1000);
        }
    },

    displaySequence: function(){                    //display the generated sequence to the user

        var that=this;

        $.each(this.genSequence, function(index, val) {     //iterate over each value in the generated array

            setTimeout(function(){

                that.flash($(that.shape+val),1,300,val);

            },500*index*that.difficulty);               // multiply timeout by how many items in the array so that they play sequentially and multiply by the difficulty modifier
        });
    },

    displayLevel: function(){                           //just display the current level on screen

        $('.level h2').text('Level: '+this.level);

    },

    displayScore: function(){                           //display current score on screen
        $('.score h2').text('Score: '+this.score);
    },

    keepScore: function(){                              //keep the score

        var multiplier=0;

        switch(this.difficulty)                         //choose points modifier based on difficulty
        {
            case '2':
                multiplier=1;
                break;

            case '1':
                multiplier=2;
                break;

            case '0.5':
                multiplier = 3;
                break;

            case '0.25':
                multiplier = 4;
                break;
        }

        this.score += (1 * multiplier);                 //work out the score

        this.displayScore();                            //display score on screen
    },

    incorrectSequence: function(){                      //if user makes a mistake

        var corPad = this.genSequence[this.turn],       //cache the pad number that should have been pressed

            that = this;
            this.active=false;
            this.displayLevel();
            this.displayScore();

        setTimeout(function(){                          //flash the pad 4 times that should have been pressed
            that.flash($(that.shape+corPad),4,300,corPad);
        },500);

        $('.start').show();                             //enable the start button again and allow difficulty selection again
        $('.difficulty').show();

    }

};
$(document).ready(function(){                           //document ready

    $('.start').on('mouseup', function(){               //initialise a game when the start button is clicked
        $(this).hide();
        game.difficulty = $('input[name=difficulty]:checked').val();
        $('.difficulty').hide();
        game.init();


    });


});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064186/how-can-i-make-a-jquery-countdown

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted when your problem is resolved. If you don't think any of the answers deserve to be marked as accepted write your own answer and mark that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working full javascript below

```
var game = { //game object
    level: 1, //current level
    turn: 0, //current turn
    difficulty: 1, // user difficulty
    score: 0, //current score
    active: false, //whether a turn is active or not
    handler: false, // whether the click and sound handlers are active
    shape: '.shape', // cached string for the pad class
    genSequence: [], //array containing the generated/randomized pads
    plaSequence: [], //array containing the users pad selections

    init: function () { //initialises the game
        if (this.handler === false) { //checks to see if handlers are already active
            this.initPadHandler(); //if not activate them
        }
        this.newGame(); //reset the game defaults

    },

    initPadHandler: function () {

        that = this;

        $('.pad').on('mouseup', function () {

            if (that.active === true) {

                var pad = parseInt($(this).data('pad'), 10);

                that.flash($(this), 1, 300, pad);

                that.logPlayerSequence(pad);

            }
        });

        this.handler = true;

    },

    newGame: function () { //resets the game and generates a starts a new level

        this.level = 1;
        this.score = 0;
        this.newLevel();
        this.displayLevel();
        this.displayScore();

        //initialize timer to 10 seconds (10.0)
        this.timer = 10;

    },

    newLevel: function () {

        this.genSequence.length = 0;
        this.plaSequence.length = 0;
        this.pos = 0;
        this.turn = 0;
        this.active = true;

        this.randomizePad(this.level); //randomize pad with the correct amount of numbers for this level
        this.displaySequence(); //show the user the sequence
    },

    flash: function (element, times, speed, pad) { //function to make the pads appear to flash

        var that = this; //cache this

        if (times > 0) { //make sure we are supposed to flash
            that.playSound(pad); //play the corresponding pad sound
            element.stop().animate({
                opacity: '1'
            }, { //animate the element to appear to flash
                duration: 50,
                complete: function () {
                    element.stop().animate({
                        opacity: '0.6'
                    }, 200);
                }
            }); //end animation

        }

        if (times > 0) { //call the flash function again until done the correct amount of times 
            setTimeout(function () {
                that.flash(element, times, speed, pad);
            }, speed);
            times -= 1; //times - 1 for each time it's called
        }
    },

    playSound: function (clip) { //plays the sound that corresponds to the pad chosen


        var sound = $('.sound' + clip)[0];
        console.log(sound);
        console.log($('.sound' + clip));
        sound.currentTime = 0; //resets audio position to the start of the clip
        sound.play(); //play the sound


    },

    randomizePad: function (passes) { //generate random numbers and push them to the generated number array iterations determined by current level

        for (i = 0; i < passes; i++) {

            this.genSequence.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        }
    },

    logPlayerSequence: function (pad) { //log the player selected pad to user array and call the checker function

        this.plaSequence.push(pad);
        this.checkSequence(pad);


    },

    checkSequence: function (pad) { //checker function to test if the pad the user pressed was next in the sequence

        that = this;

        if (pad !== this.genSequence[this.turn]) { //if not correct 

            this.incorrectSequence();

        } else { //if correct
            this.keepScore(); //update the score
            this.turn++; //incrememnt the turn

        }

        if (this.turn === this.genSequence.length) { //if completed the whole sequence

            this.level++; //increment level, display it, disable the pads wait 1 second and then reset the game
            this.displayLevel();
            this.active = false;

            // Stop counting when sequence is correct to avoid time running out before starting next level
            clearInterval(this.timerInterval);

            //Add 5.0 seconds each 5th level
            this.timer = 10 + 5 * Math.floor(this.level / 5);

            //Update timerdisplay to show fulltime while displaying next level sequence
            $(".Timer p").html(this.timer);

            setTimeout(function () {
                that.newLevel();
            }, 1000);
        }
    },

    // Countdown and update timer, call incorrectsequence when time's up
    countDown: function () {
        this.timer -= 0.1;
        $(".Timer p").html(this.timer.toFixed(1)); // Display 9.0 instad of 9
        if (this.timer < 0.1) {
            this.incorrectSequence();
        }
    },

    displaySequence: function () { //display the generated sequence to the user

        var that = this;

        var timerCount = 0;

        $.each(this.genSequence, function (index, val) { //iterate over each value in the generated array
            timerCount = index;
            setTimeout(function () {

                that.flash($(that.shape + val), 1, 300, val);

            }, 500 * index * that.difficulty); // multiply timeout by how many items in the array so that they play sequentially and multiply by the difficulty modifier
        });

        // Wait to start timer until full sequence is displayed
        setTimeout(function () {
            that.timerInterval = setInterval(function () {
                that.countDown()
            }, 100)
        }, 500 * timerCount * that.difficulty);
    },

    displayLevel: function () { //just display the current level on screen

        $('.level h2').text('Level: ' + this.level);

    },

    displayScore: function () { //display current score on screen
        $('.score h2').text('Score: ' + this.score);
    },

    keepScore: function () { //keep the score

        var multiplier = 0;

        switch (this.difficulty) //choose points modifier based on difficulty
        {
            case '2':
                multiplier = 1;
                break;

            case '1':
                multiplier = 2;
                break;

            case '0.5':
                multiplier = 3;
                break;

            case '0.25':
                multiplier = 4;
                break;
        }

        this.score += (1 * multiplier); //work out the score

        this.displayScore(); //display score on screen
    },

    incorrectSequence: function () { //if user makes a mistake

        //Stop counting down timer and display start message
        clearInterval(this.timerInterval);
        $(".Timer p").html("Get Ready your time starts when you click start");

        var corPad = this.genSequence[this.turn], //cache the pad number that should have been pressed

            that = this;
        this.active = false;
        this.displayLevel();
        this.displayScore();

        setTimeout(function () { //flash the pad 4 times that should have been pressed
            that.flash($(that.shape + corPad), 4, 300, corPad);
        }, 500);

        $('.start').show(); //enable the start button again and allow difficulty selection again
        $('.difficulty').show();

    }

};
$(document).ready(function () { //document ready

    $('.start').on('mouseup', function () { //initialise a game when the start button is clicked
        $(this).hide();
        game.difficulty = $('input[name=difficulty]:checked').val();
        $('.difficulty').hide();
        game.init();


    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has the `setInterval(function(), milliseconds)` function which could help here.

If you need to get rid of the interval once you're done with it you can store your interval like so, and then clear it:

```
var timer = setInterval(tick, 1000);
clearInterval(timer);
```

Comment: You probably meant to write `var timer = setInterval(tick, 1000);` without a set of parentheses following the function identifier, as to pass the function reference rather than call the function and pass the result.

Comment: Indeed, fixed. My JS is a little rusty, the version I used as a reference has `setInterval(function(){tick()},1000)`

Comment: but the problem i am having is implementing it with my code and my javascript, i have found dozens of examples but i cant get any of them to work with my code if u take a look at the game u can see what i want and what i mean

Comment: @Jamiex304 your github link doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this:

```
var givenTime=10000
var timeLimit
var clockInterval
resetClock()
function updateClock(){
    var now=new Date().getTime()
    if(now<timeLimit){
        //Set the displayed clock to timeLimit-now
    }
    else{
        //Time has run out
        clearInterval(clockInterval)
    }
}
function resetClock(){
    timeLimit=new Date().getTime()+givenTime
    clearInterval(clockInterval)
    clockInterval=setInterval(updateClock,10)
}
```

You have `timeLimit` set to the point in time where the timer runs out, and then a function in an interval recalculate the time left approximately once every 10 ms. Beware that you can't count on `setInterval` to fire exactly as often as you ask for, see [setTimeout or setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2549426/305545)

Comment: this is great, but the problem i am having is implementing it with my code and my javascript, i have found dozens of examples but i cant get any of them to work with my code if u take a look at the game u can see what i want and what i mean

Comment: Try, and if you fail, post your broken code.